# Read the object and get the values in Angular components

Tags: angular, object

I get the below value as exactly:

{
  "packBarCode":"Q122344",
  "usedQty":11,
  "description":"Box of Chocs",
  "customerName":"Retail Mart
 }

from an API and assign it to Array[] in my customerComponent.ts. How to I get the values of usedQty or CustomerName, for example.

What I have tried so far.. in the
    `<ng-container *ngFor="let customers of customerDetails">
            {{customers.customerName}}
    </ng-container>` .html:

I am new to Angular and not sure how to read this as this is an object. I get an error "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type ..."
Please let me know if I should put more information. Thank you

Comment: can you post your customerComponent.ts. code?

Comment: After declaring the customerDetails: object[] instead of Array][. I am able to get the values `<div class="col-lg-4">
             Details for: {{ customerDetails["customerName"] }}
        </div>` but what happens is that the debugger is throwing Cannot read property 'customerName' of undefined even though the details are visible.

Comment: I managed to declare an @Input() variable assign the above to this and now the errors have disappeared. Thank you @Saurin Vala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to access an array within an object, you should change your `*ngFor` to `*ngFor="let customer of customerDetails.customers"`. Then display the customer properties in your view by `{{ customer.customerName }}` or whatever other property you want to display.

It is hard to determine what is going on without seeing the object or array in your component.

If you are simply trying to display this object:

```
{
  "packBarCode":"Q122344",
  "usedQty":11,
  "description":"Box of Chocs",
  "customerName":"Retail Mart
}
```

in your view, you can't use the `*ngFor` directive. That is meant for iterating over arrays. Just use `{{ objectName.propertyName }}` to display what you need.

Comment: awesome.. this is it :) Thank you